# Form update empty date in database when i try to update date field using datepicker in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datepicker

When I try to update my form with date field having jquery datapicker it store empty value on my database so the date field not updated in my form ..I am using date datatype in database for date field..

I added this in html field

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="{{ old('datetime', $site->datatime) }}" name="datatime">
```

This is inside my controller

```
$site->update([
            'name'=>$request['name'],
            'copyright'=> $request['copyright'],
            'is_active'=>$request['status'] == 'true' ? 1 : 0,
            'message'=>$request['message'],
            'datatime'=>$request['datetime'],
            'url'=>$request['url'],
            'metadata'=>$request['metadata']

        ]);
```

Comment: What date format do you use in `datepicker` ?

Comment: mm/dd/year i am not using any specific date format i m using defualt date pciker formate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably due to the wrong `date` format. Mysql accept `YYYY-MM-DD`
for the date format. you can work around with the date e.x

```
$site->update([
        'name'=>$request['name'],
        'copyright'=> $request['copyright'],
        'is_active'=>$request['status'] == 'true' ? 1 : 0,
        'message'=>$request['message'],
        'datatime'=> date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request['datetime'])),
        'url'=>$request['url'],
        'metadata'=>$request['metadata']

    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="{{ old('datatime', $site->datatime) }}" name="datatime">
```

Your form input name is "datatime" and you print date as datetime. try above code and one thing Database support **YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS** format.

Comment: yes i changed the input name now...If database support YYYY-DD-MM  format how do i change the format in put field

Comment: for date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request['datetime'])) , for datetime date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request['datetime'])),